# instanceof not working?

Tags: java, generics, instanceof

I'm trying to make a class that implements Collection, so it has to have the method that removes an `Object`, so I  figured I'd just reuse the method I already created to remove an object of a generic type `T`, but it throws a compile-time error. Why won't this work?

### Code

---

```
public class ArrayPP<T> implements Collection<T>
{
  public boolean remove(Object o)
  {
    if (o instanceof T)
      remove((T)o, true);
    else
      return false;
    return true;
  }
}
```

### Error

---

```
ArrayPP.java:5: unexpected type
found   : T
required: class or array
    if (o instanceof T)
```

### Why, Java?

---

I've solved it with

```
if (t.getClass().isInstance(o))
  remove((T)o, true);
else
  return false;
return true;
```

But... I mean if someone codes "`ArrayPP<String> a = new ArrayPP<String>();`", you know that `T` is `String`, right? So how come, during runtime, it can't be seen whether `o` is a `String`? I mean, if I were to do `a.add('c');`, it wouldn't compile, because it knows that, here, the `add(T item)` method in `ArrayPP` will only accept `String`s, so why... ugh....

Comment: Change T to a concrete type then your code will compile..and u have to tell us the backing store you are implementing Collection

Comment: @smentek ArrayPP (pronounced like Array++) is a class I'm constructing that is to ArrayList as C++ is to C

Comment: @Srinivas Reddy Thatiparthy, it can't be a concrete type, don't you see?

Comment: Using `instanceof` is almost _always_ the wrong thing to do. It inverts the importance of code and data, and data should be controller in an OO world.

Comment: @Supuhstar: so it's much, much more flexible, but very complex and you can still shoot yourself in the foot without trying too hard? Sorry, I couldn't resist ;-) On a serious note and out of curiosity: what improvements would you add?

Comment: LOL actually that's not too far off XD

It will be in the next Blue Husky Toolbox, so you can check it out, yourself at http://supuh.wikia.com/wiki/Blue_Husky_Toolbox, but if you don't wanna wait, I can tell you this: It has such methods as `isolate(T... items)` which returns a new `ArrayPP<T>` of any object in the array that (1) equals any of the given items, (2) contains, ignoring case, any object in the array's `toString()` return, or (3) returns a value >= 0.5 if both it is a `Searchable` (another class I'm making, which allows for variable comparison of objects, with keywords, etc.)

Comment: Why would you need to remove an object based on its type? and how would any other type get into the collection? Really this makes no sense.

Comment: It wouldn't, but someone can pass ANY object to the method, so I wanted to ensure it was an object of type T

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For remove, you don't need to check the type. If the type doesn't match it won't be there and remove will return false anyway.

If you want a dynamic check for add(T t) you need to store the type in a field.

```
private final Class<T> tClass;

public boolean add(T t) {
   return tClass.isInstanceof(t) && collection.add(t);
}
```

Have you looked at Checked Collection in the Collections utility. It may do what you want.
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html under checkedCollection, checkedList, checkedSet, checkedMap

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `instanceof` for generic parameter types. That's because there is no information saved about T in runtime.

You should read some tutorials/docs about generics. This case is normally explained in most tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

`instanceof` can't be used with generic types because of type erasure -- there is no `T` at run-time.

Since `T` doesn't exist at run-time, what should `instanceof T` do? <del>What should `instanceof` do when `o` is `null`?</del>

One icky workabout is to use `getClass()` and make a decision based on that.

Happy coding.

Comment: The second part is easy: When `o` is `null`, then `instanceof` should evaluate to `false`: it always does.

Comment: that's odd... I can see how it wouldn't exist at compile time but... how come `T` works in almost every other case at run time?

Comment: @Supuhstar It's because of a clever compiler that gives that impression (the type-erasure is for backwards compatibility; .NET actually introduces new types for the generics) `new T()` doesn't work. Nor does `T[]` work correctly.

Answer (score 2):

T is a generic type parameter. Generic Type information is erased at runtime . So you cant possibly check if an object is instanceof T.